# Is the Java clone() method the only way to achieve polymorphic cloning?

Tags: java, clone, deep-copy, cloneable

I need to equip my class with polymorphic cloning (deep copy), i.e. I need something like this to work:

```
SuperType original = new SubType();
SuperType copy = original.clone();
```

where `original.clone()` can be substituted by any mechanism to create a deep copy, and the actual type of `copy` shall be `SubType`, because `original` is also a `SubType`.

Is the `clone()` method and `Cloneable` interface the only way to achieve this? Factory methods and copy constructors cannot by used, since the actual class is known only in run time, right? Are there any other suggested methods except those serialize-deserialize approaches, and the [Java deep-cloning library](http://code.google.com/p/cloning/) which is IMHO even worse black magic than the `clone()` method?

Thanks, Petr

Comment: You can't make a Constructor that the object you want to be cloned can be passed to?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Sure, I can, but then I would need to call `new SubType(original)` which I cannot since I do not know in time of writing the code if original is actually of class `SubType`, or `SubType2`, or `SubSubType`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually Object's `clone()` method is not allowing you to do any polymorphic calling because is `protected`. Implementing `Cloneable` is of no use either because it doesn't contain a `clone()` method.

You can do polymorphic cloning by providing a polymorphic method for the cloned classes that in turn invoke the copy constructor.

```
abstract class SuperType {
    public SuperType(SuperType t) {
    }

    public abstract SuperType deepCopy();
}

class SomeType extends SuperType {

    SomeType(SomeType t) {
        //copy constructor
    }

    @Override
    public SomeType deepCopy() {                        
        return new SomeType(this);
    }
}

 ...

SuperType original = new SubType();
SuperType copy = original.deepCopy(); //the deepCopy is called on children classes
```

See also:

[Joshua Block's opinion on cloning vs. copy constructor](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Comment: OK, that would work. But in what sense is this different from using `clone()`? Isn't the `deepCopy()` method just a different name for it? Cannot the same things you do in `deepCopy()` be done in `clone()`?

Comment: @Posa Cloning is a java "built in" way to provide object copies without the need of a copy constructor. It attempted to make life easier to programmers, but IMO it's not the case. Yes, if you take great care when overriding `clone()` (Joshua Block's Effectiva Java has a whole chapter about it), you should get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your code to work, that code is either inside the `SuperType` class or subclass, or your `SuperType` type must have a public `clone()` method. A public `clone()` method does not exist automatically, and you must implement it. You could call it anything else for that matter, e.g. `copy()`.

Your question then, is how to implement that `clone()` (or whatever you call it) method so that it does polymorphic cloning.

The way that was intended by the Java developers is to call `super.clone()`, assuming that all the classes in the inheritance hierarchy similarly implemented `clone()` to perform polymorphic cloning. This ultimately gets to the protected `Object.clone()` method, which does the magic of polymorphic cloning. Note that for `Object.clone()` to not throw an exception, your class must implement the `Cloneable` interface.

However, there are other possible ways. For example, assuming that all subclasses have a default constructor, you can do something like `this.getClass().newInstance()`. This will create an object of the right class, but the fields are not copied over. Your clone method will need to copy all the fields, and subclasses must override your clone method to copy their fields, etc. Note that it is irrelevant whether the `Cloneable` interface is implemented in this case.

Another way is, assuming that the class is Serializable, to serialize and unserialize `this`. This should create a polymorphic clone that has all the serializable fields carried over.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a copy method to SuperType and implement it in all SubTypes

```
class SuperType {

    public SuperType copy() {
              ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the `Cloneable` interface, you can create your own interface. Each class will be responsible for creating a new instance of the correct type.

Comment: It is not about the fact that I do not like `Clonable`. I do not understand the dont-use-clone panic (probably I do not quite understand the issued related to `clone` despite I have read J. Bloch's book). Why shall devise my own interface basically for the same purpose as `Clonable`? Or would the purpose of my own interface be different from that of `Clonable`?

Comment: Well, your question was "Is the clone() method and Cloneable interface the only way to achieve this?". If the clone() method is ok for you, use it. However, using a custom interface allows you to take advantage of generics.